# Swift how to declare realm results?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

How to declare Results generic

I want to declare it like global variable in `UITableViewController` and fill within `viewDidLoad` func

Here's my code

```
class ContactsController: UITableViewController {
    var contacts = Results<Contact>()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            contacts = Domain.FetchContacts()
        }
}
```

But I get error

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Results' with no
>   arguments

How can I declare it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I declared results generic like this

```
var contacts: Results<Contact>? = nil
```

Comment: For future readers, this is NOT a generic; as in Results<T>. Realm results are homogenous (can only store one type of object) and Results<Contact> will only store a Realm Contact class.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the `contacts` like this:

```
var contacts: Results<Contact>!
```

or

```
var contacts: Results<Contact>?
```

Comment: I cant declare it like that. Expected member name or constructor call after type name

Answer (score 0):

```
var contacts: Results<Contact> = realm.objects(Contact.self).filter("FALSEPREDICATE")
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to make your declaration as a optional type. Remove () and put ? after variable declaration like var contacts = Results?

Comment: I cant declare it like that. Expected member name or constructor call after type name