# How to create an empty Results<T> object?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying to create a [`MutableProperty`](http://reactivecocoa.io/reactiveswift/docs/latest/Classes/MutableProperty.html#/s:FC13ReactiveSwift15MutablePropertycFxGS0_x_) which holds a `Results` received from `Realm.objects(_:)`. 
To create the property I need to give it an initial value; hence an 'empty' `Results`.

I've tried creating one using:

```
var someThings = Results<SomeObject>()
MutableProperty(someThings)
```

But the compiler gives me the error: `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Results<SomeObject>' with no arguments`.

While I *understand* the error, I'm not really sure how to create a `Results` object in this context.
Looking at the source of `Results` I couldn't find an `init` either.

---

So my question is; how can I create a `Results` myself to use in a `MutableProperty`?

**Edit:**

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475843/swift-how-to-declare-realm-results?rq=1)...but that doesn't really help (unless I'm going to create a "wrapper" for the MutableProperty or something).

Comment: you could create a condition that is always false

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: I mean, the only way to get a `Results` is by getting one from the `realm`, see [**here**](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries) and if you want to get an empty one, I figured you'd use an impossible condition, like `NSPredicate(format: "color IS NULL AND color IS NOT NULL");` or something of that sort.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is that an 'empty' result set can only be made by fetching objects from the Realm and afterwards filter the fetched objects with a filter that returns 0 objects? That seems...ugly, but I'll try it out.

Comment: Because Realm results are lazily accessed, a `Results` with a `FALSEPREDICATE` for example would never load any data from the disk. e.g. `realm.objects(SomeObject.self).filter("FALSEPREDICATE")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help of the comments on my OP; I created a mutable property with an empty set of results by fetching objects with an 'invalid' filter.

E.g. `MutableProperty(realm.objects(SomeObject.self).filer("EMPTY SET"))`.

Comment: This is safer and more generic: `realm.objects(ofType).filter(NSPredicate(value: false))`